# What is an example of Schreyer’s Theorem?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

What is an example of Schreyer’s Theorem?
I have read lots about the theorem but can't seem to find a concrete example. Can anyone give me an example or point me in the direction of finding one?

Theorem:
[image]

Comment: Do you mean Schreier's theorem?

Comment: My textbook calls it Shreyer;s Theorem, I've attached it in an edit!

Comment: OK. That's fair enough. Neither I nor google had heard of this theorem, which is certainly not Schreier's theorem.

Comment: Sorry, I mispelled the theorem!! It's Schreyer’s Theorem

Comment: The theorem is due to Frank-Olaf Schreyer. It is implemented in the Macaulay2 language for computing syzygies. An easy example for you to try is the case when $G$ is a set of monomials. This is automatically a Gröbner basis, and the $s_{i,j}$ have a particularly nice form since every S-polynomial formed from $G$ is in fact *zero*.

Comment: See Eisenbud chapter 15.